# Unavailable Date in a Date Range

Tags: cognito-forms

I created a form with fields to enter a start date and an end date.  The form successfully rejects any dates that fall on or between a specific date range: `03/05/2023 to 10/05/2023 (dd/mm/yyyy)`.  But, it will accept start and end dates that include the restricted date range as long as the start and end dates are outside the restricted date range.

For example, the date range `02/05/2023 to 11/05/2023` would be accepted by the form even though it includes the restricted date range `03/05/2023 to 10/05/2023`.

This is how I currently work it:

```
=(FirstDayOf Required < DateTime.Today) or 
 (FirstDayOf Required.Date = DateTime.Today) or 
 (FirstDayOf Required >= "12/02/2023" and FirstDayOf Required <= "12/17/2023") or
 (FirstDayOf Required >= "03/28/2023" and FirstDayOf Required <= "04/16/2023") or
 (FirstDayOf Required >= "06/26/2023" and FirstDayOf Required <= "06/30/2023") or
 (FirstDayOf Required >= "05/20/2023" and FirstDayOf Required <= "05/20/2023") or 
 (FirstDayOf Required >= "03/11/2023" and FirstDayOf Required <= "03/18/2023") or 
 (FirstDayOf Required >= "03/04/2023" and FirstDayOf Required <= "03/05/2023")
```

How can I reject start and end dates within my restricted date range, and also ones start and end dates outside the restricted date range but whose date range includes my restricted date range?

Answer (score 0):

## Custom Error Logic

Your custom error logic should verify not only that neither `FirstDayOf` nor `LastDayOf` fall within the excluded date range, but also that no combination of dates creates a range that includes the excluded range, and that `FirstDayOf` precedes `LastDayOf`.

#### Formula

The formula assumes the excluded date range to be `03/05/2023 to 10/05/2023`

```
# Show Custom Error for 'Required' field when:

=(FirstDayOf < DateTime.Today) or
 (FirstDayOf >= "03/05/2023" and FirstDayOf <= "10/05/2023") or
 (LastDayOf <= FirstDayOf) or
 (LastDayOf >= "03/05/2023" and LastDayOf <= "10/05/2023") or
 (FirstDayOf < "03/05/2023" and LastDayOf >= "03/05/2023")
```

[image]

| Ref | Notes |
| --- | --- |
| **1** | `FirstDayOf` must be in the future |
| **2** | `FirstDayOf` can't fall within `03/05/2023 to 10/05/2023` |
| **3** | `LastDayOf` must be after `FirstDayOf` |
| **4** | `LastDayOf` can't fall within `03/05/2023 to 10/05/2023` |
| **5** | `FirstDayOf to LastDayOf` can't include `03/05/2023` |